# Dynamically routed sqlSessionFactory in mybatis

Tags: java, spring, datasource, mybatis

Is it possible to choose Mapper to execute in Mybatis?

I am using dynamically routed datasource and give it as parameter to sqlSessionFactory - it is working.

The problem is, however, that different databases may require other SQL queries (very small differences, but differences).

Is it possible to create dynamically routed `sqlSessionFactory` - and give to them other package mappers?

Answer (score 0):

This is how you obtain a session factory:
`Reader reader = Resources.getResourceAsReader("mybatis-config.xml");
 SqlSessionFactory factory = new SqlSessionFactoryBuilder().build(reader);`

A couple of things are declared in in *mybatis-config.xml*, amongst whom are the datasources and the mappers.

Then create another Mybatis config file (with its own datesource and mappers) and dynamically choose the file to build the session factory. You can still provide the connection when opening the session, although I recommend using the implicit one provided by the factory because it will match with the mapper. (Unless this is a complex application where you need to reuse the connection, e.g: to complete a transaction)